# Spring OAuth2 Resource Server ONLY

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Such a simple task and no way to do it...

I want to create a Resource Server with Spring, to work **ONLY** as a Resource Server.

**Scenario:**

- WSO2 Identity Server providing OAuth2.
- Static file server running on NginX.
- JBoss

**Flow:**

1. I load my page, it realizes i am nobody and redirects me to WSO2
2. I log in to the WSO2, which redirects me back to my page
3. I hit a button on the page, and the javascript make a request to "/hello" in the Resource Server adding the "Authentication" header.
4. The Resource Server validates the "Authentication" header against the WSO2
5. Resource Server returns with "world"

**Requeriments:**

- No OAuth2 Provider at all. The server will not save anything at all.
- No static file server
- No JSON.
- No direct jar run. No embedded Jetty not Tomcat.
- No nothing else.The less the better.
- And please NO THEORY or wild GUESSING, i want to see a complete code example so we can share with this Spring guys and make a better world.

I am looking for a freaking hello world of a Resource Server and the infamous Tonr/Sparklr represent the single worst example.

I mention JBoss because i need to deploy in it and the whole Spring Boot movement is just clashing against it. A simple WAR file is all i need.

Thanks in advance...